# Custom Plugin implementation

Tags: templating, filter

I tried to write next class:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class TaskShortcutPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    // ...
    // Shortcut sample [task id="42"]Reference to task with id = 42[/task]
    public function task($attributes, $content, $tag)
    {
             $id = $attributes['id'];    // 42
             $content;                   // Reference to task with id = 42
             $tag;                       // 'task'

             return '<a href="/task/'.$id.'" class="' .$tag. '">'.$content.'</a>';
    }
}
```

So, what next, how to implement it into CMS? Or I should use it into Twig templates?

Comment: Barif, could you be more specific about what you'd like to do? The code sample's extremely helpful, it's just tough to answer "what's next" without understanding your master plan for the plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a little ways to go before that will work as a plugin... I'd highly recommend getting a little more familiar with the basic anatomy of a plugin...

[Craft Docs - Anatomy of a Plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction#anatomy-of-a-plugin)

Basically, you'll want to take the "task" method that you have and move it to a *Variable.php file. Then you will be able to call that variable via a Twig template...

```
{{ craft.taskShortcut.task(attributes, content, tag) }}
```

You can learn more about variables here: [Template Variables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables)

However, you'll still need your main *Plugin.php file, but the methods inside will be different ([Your Primary Plugin Class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#your-primary-plugin-class)).

This will most likely be the folder structure of your plugin:

```
/craft/plugins/taskshortcut
                           /TaskShortcutPlugin.php
                           /variables/TaskShortcutVariable.php
```